# Is there a way to sort by more than one field in Crystal Reports?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2005, sorting, crystal-reports

I'm using Crystal Report with VB.NET in Visual Studio 2005.

I have report that works if I pass in a list of `List(Of Stuff)`.  I had been sorting the report by one of the members of `Stuff` but a need now to sort first by one member, like `Stuff.StatusCode` and then by another member, like `Stuff.ItemNumber`.

Can I do this just be having more than one `SortField` member, or do I need to do it some other way?

Thanks as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it.  I used the Record Sort Expert:

- Right-click outside report area
- Report -> Record Sort Expert